# Set image in UIImageView with original Dimension in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

My UIImageView with constant Width*Height is 100*100 on UIView, But image i want to show in this UIImageView is 25*25 (original dimension ).

I don't want to stretch image. i try UIImageView ContentMode property but did't work.

This i don't want.tried sizeToFit and aspectCenter mode.

[image]

[image]

I need following result,For small images

[image]

How to do that(With out stretching original image dimension and constant UIImageView dimension).What will be case if image is bigger than UIImageView ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you used [yourImage sizeToFit] ?

Comment: Hmm @Hima not working.

Comment: What is the scenario that uiimageview is of 100*100 and image is of 25*25 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call - sizeToFit
That should do exactly what you need.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit

Comment: image appear at top left corner and sometime too big image. breaking height width constraints.

Comment: Did you center the image at all by setting the appropriate content mode? Or re-align the UIImageView accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Try this 
(Objective-C):

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

(Swift):

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;
```

Comment: not working for big  image size. ex. 300*300 it not show complete image.

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If that's the case remove the size constraints from the image.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

no matter image is small or big it will scale the image.

if you don't want to stretch image than you have to resize `UIImageView` to image size

You can obtain image size from UIImage. 
for eg

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
float imgHeight = image.size.height;
float imgWidth = image.size.width;
```